# C++ operator->() overload

Tags: c++, memory, overloading, operator-keyword, member

Okay, since it's my first question, let me try again. I edited post and changed code to make it easier for you all to understand.

```
template <typename T>
class Structure
{
protected:
    DWORD64 _instanceAddress;
    T _structPointer;
public:
    Structure<T>(DWORD64 instanceAddress);
    ~Structure();
    T* operator->();
};

template <typename T>
T* Structure<T>::operator->()
{
    Driver::ReadMemory( _instanceAddress, sizeof(T), &_structPointer );
    return static_cast<T*>( &_structPointer );
}

struct C
{
    int some_value;
}

struct B
{
    C *pointer_to_C;
}

struct A
{
    B *pointer_to_B;
}

//CODE

Structure<A> myStructure(DWORD64 AddressInMemory);

myStructure->pointer_to_B->pointer_to_C->some_value;
```

I'm reading other process memory through driver. Address of structure I'm trying to reach is static, so there is nothing to worry about. Is there any way that I can change my memory reading class to make it work like I've specified in bottom line of code? The ideal situation would be to do some changes in `operator->()` overload to do some checks regarding type user is trying to reach.

It should allow to define only lowest Structure in pointer chain and then just dereference it like its being done normally on mother-process raw memory.

So I'm imagining it would be something like that:

```
template <typename T>
T* Structure<T>::operator->(type_of_desired_variable var_name)
```

check if `var_name` is `int` or `float`

if not then define new `Structure<type_of_desired_variable>` and store it somewhere, then call its `operator->()`

Comment: You can return anything you can apply `operator->` to from `operator->` (it keeps getting called on the results until you end up with a `T*`). This means you can return a smart pointer from `operator->`, but whether that helps you I don't know.

Comment: Just an aside - if your class has an `init` function, there's a problem with your class.

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code in your question, there's far too much to read, and most of it isn't relevant to your specific question.

Comment: @erip. I disagree with the dogmatic use of this statement. Often it is right, sometimes it is not. This is not a religious forum so let's focus on answering Patryk's question.

Comment: @Chiel C++ offers a constructor, which is what an `init` function should be. The only difference is the constructor can handle failure. I don't think this is dogmatic at all: if you don't use an `init` function, you won't need an overload. To think SO is just about answering questions and not offering solutions is misguided.